# Get The Category Link outside The Loop In WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, categories

Is there any ways to get category link outside the loop? So I can place the code everywhere.
In case I want 
For example: I want to create a custom title category, then link to the specific category

```
<a href="link_to_category"> CUSTOMTITLE </a>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `<?php get_the_category( $id ) ?>`, the following is the relevant reference from the Codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Bear in mind a post can be in more than one category, so this is returned as an array of category objects.  To create the link itself (I think this'll likely only work with permalinks enabled) you can use the `category_nicename` property which returns the slug.

You'll see this type of thing used in custom breadcrumbs a lot, I've pasted some code for that below.  It uses the first category in the array. Remember if you are outwith the loop to declare the `$post` variable global;

```
<?php
global $post;
$category = get_the_category();
$thisCat = $category[0];

echo '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/' . $thisCat->category_nicename . '">CUSTOM TITLE</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks, McNab. Unfortunately, this is not solved my problem. Thanks anyway.